# When Staring the mongoDB server, it hits below errors

Tags: mongodb

When Staring the mongoDB server, it hits below errors, and the mongoDB server is unable to start.

```
2015-08-23T17:38:39.583+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\data\db\journal
2015-08-23T17:38:39.587+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-08-23T17:38:39.588+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten]
2015-08-23T17:38:39.589+0530 E JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Insufficient free space for journal files
2015-08-23T17:38:39.589+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in C:\data\db\journal or use --smallfiles
2015-08-23T17:38:39.590+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten]
2015-08-23T17:38:39.590+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
2015-08-23T17:38:39.591+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-08-23T17:38:39.592+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.592+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.593+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.593+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.593+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.594+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-08-23T17:38:39.594+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-08-23T17:38:39.595+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

When C:\data is deleted it works. I followed [this](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/old-lock-file-datadbmongod-lock-probably-means-unclean-shutdown/) tutorial. But it didn't work. Can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `"Insufficient free space"` is mentioned in the error message - have you handled/considered this issue?

Comment: Problem is when I run mongod on the cmd above error messages will display on it.

Comment: Please take another look at my comment **and** at the error message text.
The error message is saying that you don't have enough free space. Have you checked that you have enough free space to start the `mongod` instance?

Comment: I searched about what you said in the above comment. When i used "mongod --smallfiles" command it works. So i think problem is on the memory space. How many size of memory needs to run mongodb?

Comment: Not memory - hard drive space. All of the information you are asking for is inside the error message - please read it carefully - all the numbers and details are there.

Comment: I'll do it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lix says, all the information is inside the error message. Especially in:

> Insufficient free space for journal files
>    Please make at least 3379MB available in C:\data\db\journal or use --smallfiles

If you free at least 3379MB in your C partition you should be able to start the MongoDB server.